# Not able to build app in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

While building app in Android Studio 2.1.1 working under Ubuntu Linux 16.04 and Java version 1.8.0_92, I get the following error,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/username/Android/Sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aidl''

Looking in classpath from com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader@7a4f0f29 for /com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Found library resource at jar:file:/home/username/android-studio/lib/jna.jar!/com/sun/jna/linux-x86-64/libjnidispatch.so
Trying /home/username/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna--1130344529/jna6729363104281071976.tmp
Found jnidispatch at /home/username/.AndroidStudio2.1/system/tmp/jna--1130344529/jna6729363104281071976.tmp
[  12820]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Errors during XML parse:
[  12820]   WARN - dea.updater.SdkComponentSource - Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
[  69882]   WARN - 2.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Errors during XML parse:
[  69882]   WARN - 2.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
[  70113]   WARN - 2.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Errors during XML parse:
[  70113]   WARN - 2.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
[ 256322]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - button doesn't exist 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: button doesn't exist 0
        at java.awt.event.InputEvent.getMaskForButton(InputEvent.java:247)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.isMouseGrab(Container.java:4486)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4511)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved by

(i) deleting all the .iml files and the .idea directory in the app directory tree,

(ii) deleting the .android directory in the login user's home directory,

(iii) deleting all the .AndroidStudio?.? directories in the login user's home directory, and

(iv) re-installing Android Studio 2.1.1

The final configuration was Java 1.8.0_91, Android Studio 2.1.1 and Play services 9.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes have a similar problems... Try to Clean your project.. Also, closing/reopening Android studio helps.

Comment: Tried cleaning project and closing/opening Android Studio. Still getting the same error.